# SilverLight/WPF viewmodel Command property

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have viewmodel which has below property of type ICommand

```
    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand(SaveEventHandler, CanSave);
        }
    }
```

This SaveCommand is bound to the save button command property in the .xaml file. I have below question from above context

1. When exactly binding happens?
2. Does the SaveCommand getter called only once of a viewmodel instance?
3. Is it fine to return **new DelegateCommand** in the SaveCommand getter or do I need to declare private variable in viewmodel for a savecommand and initialize in the constructor and just use that private variable to return in the getter of savecommand?

Comment: 1: Not relevant. 2: Do not rely on it. 3: No it's not fine (IMO). Better write `public ICommand SaveCommand { get; } = new DelegateCommand(SaveEventHandler, CanSave);`

Comment: Hi Clemens, Thanks for the quick response. Do you have any idea when the getter get called?

Comment: Put a breakpoint and try it out.

Comment: 3 - don't do that. Use lazy initialization and cache command in private field. 1 & 2 - what is your *real* question? Why do you interesting it at all?

Comment: Hi Dennis, Thanks for the response. SaveEventHandler is executed multiple times when the save button is clicked once. Note that only once instance of view model is created. This issue is happening in the production environment only. This is the silverlight application.  So trying to understand why SaveEventHandler is called multiple time when button is clicked once.

Comment: Hi Clemeens, I used the break point In development environment, and getter is called only once.